# binomial expansion used in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I am having trouble understanding the following:

[image]
[image]

now the binomial expansion is defined:

[image]

while it not obvious how the left hand side could equal the right hand side, I can see the inequality easily.

So why is the LHS = RHS?

in any case if n=0 then the RHS will be 1 but the LHS will be 2.

*okay comments have pointed out if the number range is defined then my last statement becomes irrelevant.  That leaves just the inequality as a question.*

Comment: this expansion is defined for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The problem here is in the $\ldots$ notation. If the binomial expansion gets properly defined, using sum notation, it also holds for $n = 0$.

Comment: I don't see any definition of any relationship between $m$ and $n$ so it is unintelligible.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: yes you're right the equation was in the wrong place now edited to make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sort of hard to figure out what your difficulty is.  There are two steps here.  One is to take the binomial theorem and plug in $1$ for $x$ and $1$ for $y$ and $2m+1$ for $n$.  That gives you your equality.  Second, the inequality follows because every term in the expansion is positive.  Since the right side is missing most of the terms, it has to be less than the left side.

Comment: yes but I do not see how they could be equal in the greater than or equal part?

Comment: Equality happens when $m=0$.